# Qt for Android MapboxGL Application Crashes if I switch maptype when Internet is Off

Tags: android, qt, qml, mapbox-gl

I have a simple QML Map App in Android. And if I change the activeMapType when the Internet is Off the App simply crashes. How to stop the app from crashing?

```
    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        bearing: 0
        onZoomLevelChanged: {
            calculateScale()
        }
        activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[mapType]
        plugin: Plugin {
            id: mapPlugin
            name: "mapboxgl"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to reproduce this error on a developing comp? Did you try to debug? Do you have some error/warning messages on a target platform?

Comment: @folibis Sorry for the delay. I am getting the error as below: [ ERROR ]  "{unknown}[Style]: Failed to load tile 16/46219/29328=>16 for source composite: Host api.mapbox.com not found". This error is generated if you don't have internet. I have the app installed on Lenovo Tab K10.